# Slides not showing on flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I'm building a new homepage WordPress template. The template uses [Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com) to display Vimeo videos, a simple title and description.

I've followed the [FlexSlider documentation](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/video.html) to the letter, but the slides are all coming up blank.

Here's what I'm seeing via the Chrome Inspector:

```
.flexslider .slides > li {
    display: none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

For some reason the JQuery isn't kicking in. I've tried removing the inline styles from the `<li>` tags. I've also tried knocking out the lightbox script that I have running. Nothing seems to be working.

Can you see what's causing this? I've uploaded a demo here: http://bit.ly/1Sgpu99

**UPDATE**

Here's the relevant source from the template:

```
<?php // Begin main loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php // Begin carousel repeater
        if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                    <?php while( have_rows('slides') ): the_row(); 
                        // vars
                        $background_image = get_sub_field('background_image');
                        $video = get_sub_field('video');
                        $title = get_sub_field('title');
                        $description = get_sub_field('description');
                        $background_image = get_sub_field('background_image');
                    ?>
                        <li class="slide" style="background: url(<?php echo $background_image; ?>) no-repeat center; background-size: cover;">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="half">
                                    <div class="video"><?php echo $video; ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="half last">
                                    <header class="entry-header">
                                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
                                    </header>
                                    <?php echo $description; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- .container -->
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- .flexslider -->
            </div><!-- .flex-container -->
        <?php // End repeater 
        endif; ?>
 <?php // End main loop
endwhile;  ?>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted just the relevant code rather than a link to the website. There are so many plugins and JS that its difficult to see whats happening on the page.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason flexslider has not been initialized in your page.

If you put this code in Chrome or Firefox console

```
jQuery(".flexslider")
    .flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      useCSS: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      smoothHeight: true,
      before: function(slider){
        $f(player).api('pause');
      }
  });
```

and hit enter, the slider is showing ( whit completely broken css, but this is another question :) )

I can't tell from provided code why slider is not initialized, but you must debug your `.js` code, not `.php`. Put some console.log() in .js file where slider is initialized, to be sure that file is loaded, use `wp_enqueue_script()` to load your `.js`files with proper dependence to be sure that files are loaded in proper order and so on.

Comment: That's really strange. I'm using the `wp_enqueue_script()` method correctly as everything is built under _S.

Comment: This was only suggestion, I can't give more accurate answer without do some debugging :( But in my opinion problem is somewhere in javascript files.

Comment: Your answer has really helped buddy :) Your suggestion has led me to custom.js file which is a complete mess. Hopefully a cleanup should do the trick. I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If I can help with something else ... :) And will be glad if you mark your question as accepted of course :))))

Comment: All fixed! I wrote the JS a long time ago before I really knew what I was doing. Something within the custom.js was breaking the slider. Thanks again.